# Show/Hide jQuery, shows all of the divs instead of one that was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show

I am trying to use jQuery show `div`, but the problem I have is that it all of the `divs` with same class are being shown instead of the one that was clicked.

So basically, once `VIEW MORE` is clicked, the `div` should be visible and VIEW MORE should be hidden, then if the `VIEW MORE` in another `div` is clicked, same thing should happen in that `div` too.

```js
$('.show-more').click(function() {
  $('.text-hidden').show();
  $(this).hide()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="forms">
  <h2>New Forms</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<span class="show-more">VIEW MORE</span>
<div class="forms text-hidden">
  <ul>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="forms">
  <h2>Old Forms</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<span class="show-more">VIEW MORE</span>
<div class="forms text-hidden">
  <ul>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I am not a big pro on jquery/javascript so please bear with me on this one.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.next()` to achive what you want

`$(this).next(".text-hidden").show()`

This will select the next element with the class `text-hidden` and show it

Example below.

```js
$('.show-more').click(function() {
  $(this).next(".text-hidden").show();
  $(this).hide()
});
```

```css
.text-hidden {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="forms">
  <h2>New Forms</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<span class="show-more">VIEW MORE</span>
<div class="forms text-hidden">
  <ul>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="forms">
  <h2>Old Forms</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<span class="show-more">VIEW MORE</span>
<div class="forms text-hidden">
  <ul>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This will target *every* matching element:

```
$('.text-hidden').show();
```

What you want instead is to traverse the DOM from the clicked element to find a specific element relative to that clicked element.  From your HTML, it looks like what you want is the "next `.text-hidden`", which would be something like this:

```
$(this).next('.text-hidden').show();
```